# Is there a pythonic way to check whether OS is a 64bit Ubuntu?

Tags: python, operating-system, uname, lsb

Is there a pythonic way to check whether OS is a 64bit Ubuntu?

Currently, I've been doing it as such:

```
import os

def check_is_linux(distro, architecture, err_msg):
    try:
        this_os = os.popen('lsb_release -d').read()
        this_arch = os.popen('uname -a').read()
        assert distro in this_os and architecture in this_arch, err_msg
    except:
        print(err_msg)

def check_is_64bit_ubuntu(err_msg):
    check_is_linux('Ubuntu', 'x86_64', err_msg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`platform` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) to get distribution and processor information:

```
import platform

def is_linux(distro, architecture):
    if not platform.system() == 'Linux':
        return False

    if platform.linux_distribution()[0].lower() != distro:
        return False

    return platform.processor() == architecture

def is_64bit_ubuntu():
    return is_linux('ubuntu', 'x86_64')

if not is_64bit_ubuntu():
    print(err_msg)
```

Comment: Thanks!! `platform` is great!! But minor mistake, it should be `is_linux('ubuntu', 'x86_64')` because of `platform.linux_distribution()[0].lower()`

Comment: @alvas: ah, yes, my mistake. Glad I was of help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the functionality provided by the `platform` module, specifically platform.architecture and platform.uname.